# Get user's consent to autoplay video with javascript confirm() dialog on page load

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, confirm, autoplay

I've understood that modern browsers disable video autoplay if the sound is enabled.
But it's still possible to play the video if the visitor clicks on a button, for example.

What I want to do is to get user's consent to play the video with sound with a javascript confirm() dialog on page load.

It's important for me that the user can't browse the website before it has either accepted or declined the video playing. So, the javascript confirm() dialog seems well adapted.

However, the confirm() dialog started on page load seems not enough for the browser to consider the visitor has made a deliberate action.

Is there a tip to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: Create your custom confirm dialog. Web Audio API's user gesture is normally a `click` event, which doesn't apply to `confirm()`

Comment: @Spectric could you please explain how to do that/give more informations ? I'm a beginner with Javascript.

Comment: The browser considers user interaction as a click. When you use the confirm dialog, the browser doesn't record clicks on the dialog itself. Therefore, it won't be considered as a user interaction. You'll have to create your own dialog.